# Cross-platform way to check if "DUAL" table exists in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, database-table

I have an application that has the potential to use either an Oracle, MySQL, or SQL Server. In a few queries, I need to use the "DUAL" table, for example:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MYTABLE) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM DUAL
```

However, the "DUAL" table is not supported in SQL Server.

Is there a SQL statement I can use that will check if the "DUAL" table is supported? This way I can branch to a different query if it's not supported.

I tried querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES, but the "DUAL" table is not listed there, even in Oracle and MySQL where it's supported.

Comment: Just as the table isn't standard, the syntax for checking which tables exist isn't standard.  Nor is the syntax for numerous other functions, expressions, etc.  Thus, your SQL statements should already be customised for the platform you're running against *(not just the use of DUAL)*.  How come your application code doesn't already know what platform the server is?  This feels like you're trying to solve one smaller detail from a much bigger problem.

Comment: @MatBailie My application does know the platform, but I would like to let the database tell me if DUAL is supported, that way if I ever do support another database, I don't have to modify my code.

Comment: But you'll have to modify the code anyway, because that check would be different itself on each platform.  What's wrong with an if or switch?  If you know it's MySQL or Oracle, you know you can use `dual`, else you can't unless it's been manually created.

Comment: @TheImpaler I never said "My application does not know the platform". You misread.

Comment: Writing SQL code that is portable between several brands of RDBMS products is largely a myth. I implemented a database library that supported Oracle, Microsoft, DB2, MySQL, PostgreSQL, and SQLite. One ultimately has to write an Adapter pattern, and customize the SQL for each brand.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is simply to create a `dual` table or view with one row in SQL Server.  MySQL accepts `dual`.

Do this once and forget about it.

Comment: Although this would work...I'm hoping there is a cleaner solution that won't require creating an empty table

Comment: @user3163495 . . . If you want to write any code that is portable among the three databases, this is recommended.  Of course, you will still be very limited in what you can express, but there will at least be some queries.

Comment: Saying that you wouldn't want to create an **empty table**: well, in Oracle, `dual` contains **one row**, it isn't empty. A lot of Oracle code would break if someone deletes it. Therefore, yes, I agree with Gordon: `create table dual (dummy char(1)); insert into dual values ('X');` and forget about it.